# GCM in Android wearable

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, wear-os

Can we create an app that will receive push notification from a server, like in Phones and Glass

Since we have WiFi enabled Watches available now, we can connect to internet, but does it support push from external entity(Server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible AFIK.

You need to push the message to the phone and forward the message via the [Data API](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html). You need to keep in mind that the WiFi connection is only a fallback when the bluetooth connection is not available.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it now from [Android Wear 2.0 Developer Preview](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/index.html). Android can wear can directly make own network calls and same old FCM/GCM will work.

Under  Network Access and Cloud Messaging

> Android Wear apps can make their own network requests. When a watch has a Bluetooth connection to a phone, the watch's network traffic is proxied through the phone. When a phone is unavailable, Wi-Fi and cellular networks are used, depending on the hardware. The Wear platform handles transitions between networks. A watch's network access thus does not require the [Wearable Data Layer API](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).
>
> For sending notifications, apps can directly use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), which replaces Google Cloud Messaging, or continue to use GCM.
>
> No APIs for network access or FCM are specific to Android Wear. Refer to the existing documentation about [connecting to a network](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) and [cloud messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

More details - https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/standalone-apps.html#network_access